# Xpath query to get the parent Element text and its child element attribute values?

Tags: python, xpath

I have the following XML :

```
<sample>
  <Message number="2">
  <Title>Program pointer has been reset</Title> 
  <Description>
  The program pointer of task 
  <arg format="%s" ordinal="3" /> 
  has been reset. 
  </Description>
  </Message>
</sample>
```

I'm trying to get the decription text with arg attribute values. Something like `"The program pointer of task %s 3 has been reset."`

and my attempt looked something like

```
'/sample//Message[@number = $mId]/Description'
```

but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 you could use `string-join(/sample//Message[@number = 2]/Description/(text() | */@*), '')`. I am not sure whether Python gives you access to an XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 library.

Comment: its work........thanx alot man....actually im using pydom xpath 0.1 lib..can you please provide me some links to study more about how to use xpath queries...again thanx for your help..:-)